# Postgresql Fill in missing dates using raw sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date, join, select

I have the following tables (simplified below):

`Orders:`

```
<id: 1, shipping: 6.0, price: 20.0>
<id: 2, shipping: 10.0, price: 30.0>
<id: 3, shipping: 7.0, price: 12.0>
<id: 4, shipping: 5.0, price: 0.0> #0 dollars because it was updated after return
```

`Sales`:

```
<id: 1, order_id: 1, price:10.0, qty:2, date: "2020-06-01T01:16:15-04:00">
<id: 2, order_id: 1, price:9.0, qty: 1, date: "2020-06-01T01:16:15-04:00">
<id: 3, order_id: 2, price:15.0, qty:2, date: "2020-06-01T01:23:53-04:00">
<id: 4, order_id: 3, price:4.0, qty: 1, date: "2020-06-01T20:28:18-04:00">
<id: 5, order_id: 3, price:4.0, qty: 2, date: "2020-06-01T20:31:15-04:00">
<id: 6, order_id: 4, price:29.0, qty:1, date: "2020-06-03T20:16:15-04:00">
```

`Refunds`:

```
<id: 1, order_id: 1, qty:1, amount: 9.0, date: "2020-06-01T01:23:15-04:00">
<id: 2, order_id: 4, qty:1, amount: 29.0, date: "2020-06-04T03:34:53-04:00">
```

I'm writing raw sql to calculate the `shipping` (i.e sum(orders.shipping)), `total orders` (i.e COUNT(DISTINCT orders.id)) and `net sales`(i.e sales.price * sales.qty - COALESCE(refunds.refund_amount, 0)) grouped by the days. The search is going to take a `min_date` and `max_date` in format: `YYYY-MM-DDThh24:mi:ss` to filter out the sales or refunds that aren't within the date range. The problem I'm having is using `generate_series` to add in all the days that don't exist in the tables with the values all set to 0. So a sample response if min_date = 2020-06-01T00:00:00 and max_date = 2020-06-05T23:59:59 would be something like:

```
"2020-06-01": {shipping: 6, total_orders: 3, net_sales: 62.0},
"2020-06-02": {shipping: 0, total_orders: 0, net_sales: 0}, --> newly added
"2020-06-03": {shipping: 5, total_orders: 1, net_sales: 29},
"2020-06-04": {shipping: 0, total_orders: 1, net_sales: -29.0},
"2020-06-05": {shipping: 0, total_orders: 0, net_sales: 0} --> newly added.
```

Can anyone help me receive the desired results above. I've seen examples but I can't get it to work with my scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this would do what you want:

```
select 
    d.dt, 
    o.shipping,
    s.total_orders,
    coalesce(s.sales_amount, 0) - coalesce(r.refound_amount, 0) net_sales
from generate_series(?::timestamp, ?::timestamp, interval '1 day') d(dt)
left join lateral (
    select 
        count(distinct order_id) total_orders,
        sum(price * quantity) sales_amount,
        array_agg(order_id) order_ids
    from sales s
    where s.date >= d.dt and s.date < d.dt + interval '1 day'
) s on true
left join lateral (
    select sum(o.shipping) shipping
    from orders o
    where o.id = any(s.order_ids)
) o on true
left join lateral (
    select sum(r.amount) refound_amount
    from refunds r
    where r.order_id = any(s.order_ids)
) r on true
```

The query starts by generating all dates within the given interval (the `?` represent the two date parameters).

Then, we use a `lateral join` with an aggregate query to bring the information about all sales that occur within the period. Another `later join` brings the shippings that correspond to the `order_id`s selected by the first lateral join, and another one brings the corresponding refunds.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side` at the line: `where o.id = any(s.order_id)`

Comment: @tee: please run the query to exactly as provided. My code has `where o.id = any(s.order_ids)` (note the `s` at the end)

Comment: ahh i see..I had modified it a bit because the original post is a simplified version of the problem. But now it works! Thanks